# Javascript Detect Dialog "example.com wants to open this application" is opening

Tags: javascript, dialog

I want to detect this dialog is opening by using `javascript`. Are there any way to do that?. Because behaviour of this dialog is different with `js` `alert`, if using `alert` all `js` on webpage will stop working but when this `dialog` is opening, `js` is still working.

[image]

Related link that `Puppeteer` seem able to detect dialog is opening

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-detect-a-alert-in-puppeteer

Comment: This is not an alert, it doesn't come from JavaScript. It's a built-in dialog that the browser displays when some action requires user approval. I don't think you can intercept it, just like you can't intercept file-open dialogs.

Comment: Yes I know, I mentioned alert as an example. The purpose is how to detect that is dialog opening.